# postgresql alter table sequence id starting at a given value

Tags: postgresql, nextval

The 'id' from my table 'biblios' didn't autoincrement. It had already data in it and the 'id' go from 112 to 175.

I altered the table to add nextval, doing this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE biblios_id_seq
OWNED by biblios.id;
ALTER TABLE biblios
ALTER id
SET DEFAULT nextval('biblios_id_seq'::regclass);
```

This starts the id at '1'.

How do I make the autoincrement continue at '176' ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the sequence is already created, you can reset it using

```
SELECT setval('biblios_id_seq', max(id)) FROM biblios;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MINVALUE minvalue:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE biblios_id_seq
MINVALUE 176
OWNED by biblios.id;
ALTER TABLE biblios
ALTER id
SET DEFAULT nextval('biblios_id_seq'::regclass);
```